# Do I need a hosting package for each domain?

Tags: dns, hosting, web-hosting

I have a basic domain and hosting package from 1&1.ca

If I wanted to buy a second domain from 1&1.ca do I have to get a second hosting package as well?

One domain would be .ca and one would be .com

Answer (score 1):

You wont need to buy another hosting package.
You can link 2 domain to 1 account, its called parked domain.

From google:

> Parked domains are additional domains hosted on your account which
>   display the same website as your primary domain and share web
>   statistics as well; however, you can give the parked domain its own
>   email boxes.

You can update it in your cpanel under parked domains.

Guide from hostgator:
http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/what-is-a-parked-domain-how-do-i-create-and-delete-one

Comment: Wait, so that explanation says "hosted on your account which display the same website" but I don't want to do that. I want to show 2 different websites that each have their own domain name.

Comment: It all depends on what backend system you are running. But it is possibole to display diffrent content for each domain

Answer (score 0):

I contacted 1&1 and here is what they told me:

- Their basic hosting package includes only 1 website (so multiple domains are only for parking I assume)
- If you get one of their "unlimited" packages then you can have unlimited domains pointing at unlimited websites hosted on 1 web hosting package (the unlimited one)
- Their 2nd cheapest of 3 plans has unlimited websites but caps the size of files you can have on the server to 64MB. So if your websites are large, then you will be limited by the memory of the package.